# Qt: How to make Incompatible sender/receiver arguments compatible?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is the code where I use connect,

```
connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), ui.widget_2, SLOT(paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)));//draw lines
```

I use it to go to the slot paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) where I can draw some lines. But I have a message while debugging or running the program which is

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
    QTimer::timeout() --> MapWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)

{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    myTimer = new QTimer(this);
...
    connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), ui.widget_2, SLOT(paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)));//draw lines
...
}
```

**ui.widget_2** is an instance of mapWidget.

mapWidget.cpp

```
void MapWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
...
}
```

I know that the arguments of the signal and slot are incompatible, but I don't know how to make them compatible. It seems that the arguments of MapWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) can't be ignored, nor can I add arguments to timeout().

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t try to connect to `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)`; that method isn’t a slot-method, so calling it via a signal wouldn't work even if you were somehow able to get the right arguments passed to it.  Instead connect to the `update()` slot, which will see to it that the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` method is called from the proper context, ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

## OP's specific use-case: Using a QTimer to paint a widget.

Jeremy Friesner's answer is correct for this use case.

## General answer to title question, *"How to make Incompatible sender/receiver arguments compatible?"*

Use the **new Qt 5 version of `QObject::connect()`**: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html

The Qt 5 style connect can do implicit conversions:

```
// OK: The new version of connect() lets the compiler convert int to double
connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
        doubleSpinBox, &QDoubleSpinBox::setValue);

// ERROR: The old version of connect() needs the parameter types to be exactly the same
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        doubleSpinBox, SLOT(setValue(double)));
```

Furthermore, you can use a **lambda expression** to connect to a slot whose parameters are truly incompatible with the signal parameters:

```
// Using QTimer::timeout() to trigger a call to QLabel::setText(const QString&)
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=] {
    label->setText( QTime::currentTime()->toString() );
});
```